# Why my ASP.net core application does not accept manually generated tokens

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, antiforgerytoken

Why my ASP.net core application does not accept manually generated tokens

For Ajax requests, I send both header token and cookie token by the request

This is the code I use to create the header Token

```
public class TokenController : Controller
{
    private readonly IAntiforgery _antiforgery;

    public TokenController(IAntiforgery antiforgery)
    {
        _antiforgery = antiforgery;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetHeaderToken()
    {
        var tokens = _antiforgery.GetTokens(HttpContext);

        return Json(tokens.RequestToken);
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    //...
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //...
        services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
        {
            options.HeaderName = "HeaderToken";
            options.FormFieldName = "FieldToken";
            options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder
            {
                Name = "CookieToken",
                IsEssential = true,
                HttpOnly = true,
                SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest,
                SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax
            };
        });

        services.AddControllers(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
        });

        services.AddRazorPages(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions
                .ConfigureFilter(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
        })
        .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
    }
}
```

js:

```
$.ajax = function(options)
{
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) =>
    {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open(options.method, options.url, true);

        xhr.onerror = function()
        {
            //...
        };

        xhr.onload = function()
        {
            //...
        };

        if (options.method.toLowerCase() === 'get')
        {
            xhr.send($.param(options.data));
        }
        else
        {
            var data = options.data;

            var $tokenField = $(`[name="FieldToken"]`);

            if ($tokenField.length === 0)
            {
                await $.ajax({
                    url: 'Token/GetHeaderToken',
                    method: 'get',
                    complete: function(x)
                    {
                         data["FieldToken"] = x.responseText;
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                data["FieldToken"] = $tokenField.first().val();
            }

            xhr.send(getFormData(options.data));
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: You can't just change where tokens come from. If you're not sending the header token in the header, then the antiforgery validation won't work... Show the JavaScript code that sends the tokens in the request.

Comment: I added the JS code

Comment: Well, there you go, you are putting the form field token in the header token, and in the form field (although it's not clear that the form field is getting in there, since it could possibly not be). The tokens have to be different.

Comment: I am currently using the token field value in the header without any problems, in any case I updated the JavaScript code and used the token in the data but the problem was not solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get token from form element:

TokenController.cs

```
public class TokenController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return PartialView("Token");
    }
}
```

Token.cshtml:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
<form method="post"></form>
```

js:

```
$.ajax = function(options)
{
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) =>
    {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onerror = function()
        {
            //...
        };

        xhr.onload = function()
        {
            //...
        };

        if (options.method.toLowerCase() === 'get')
        {
            xhr.open(options.method, `${options.url}?${$.param(options.data)}`, true);

            xhr.send();
        }
        else
        {
            var $tokenField = $(`[name="FieldToken"]`);

            if ($tokenField.length === 0)
            {
                await $.ajax({
                    url: 'Token/GetHeaderToken',
                    method: 'get',
                    complete: function(x)
                    {
                        $('body').append(x.responseText);
                    }
                });

                $tokenField = $(`[name="FieldToken"]`);
            }

            xhr.open(options.method, options.url, true);

            xhr.setRequestHeader("HeaderToken", $tokenField.first().val());

            xhr.send(getFormData(options.data));
        }
    });
};
```